# Digital Ocean Django app is only working with Debug=True

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

I am using ubuntu os in Digital Ocean and when I deployed my django/Python app, it works only when I mention **`Debug=True`**.

I tried this **`ALLOWEDHOSTS = ['*'] & ALLOWEDHOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']`**. I also tried the IP that was assigned for the droplet, even then it simply throws error.

Apart from that, with Debug being `True`, when I start the server and navigate to browser I see that its not loading the css/js files in static folder.

Any help will be much appreciated.

I have seen there were some questions which are similar to this but none of them were properly answered.

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/supchang/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/ssupchang/static; 
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }     
}
```

**`Gunicorn.conf`**

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /home/django

exec gunicorn \
    --name=supchang \
    --pythonpath=ssupchang \
    --bind=127.0.0.1:9000 \
    --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py \
    ssupchang.wsgi:application
```

**`Logs`**

```
2014/10/29 00:32:23 [error] 14812#0: *68 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/js/trainee_app_get_subcategories_results.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/js/trainee_app_get_subcategories_results.js?_=1414556121448 HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:32:23 [error] 14812#0: *68 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/js/trainee_app_get_subcategories_results.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/js/trainee_app_get_subcategories_results.js?_=1414556121449 HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:32:23 [error] 14812#0: *78 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/js/trainee_app_get_subcategories_results.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/js/trainee_app_get_subcategories_results.js?_=1414556121450 HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:32:23 [error] 14812#0: *78 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/js/trainee_app_get_subcategories_results.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/js/trainee_app_get_subcategories_results.js?_=1414556121451 HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:32:23 [error] 14812#0: *78 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/js/trainee_app_get_subcategories_results.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/js/trainee_app_get_subcategories_results.js?_=1414556121452 HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:32:23 [error] 14811#0: *38 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/js/trainee_app_get_subcategories_results.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/js/trainee_app_get_subcategories_results.js?_=1414556121453 HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:32:23 [error] 14811#0: *38 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/js/trainee_app_get_subcategories_results.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/js/trainee_app_get_subcategories_results.js?_=1414556121454 HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:32:27 [error] 14811#0: *38 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/css/master.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/css/master.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:32:27 [error] 14812#0: *78 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/css/normalize.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/css/normalize.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:32:27 [error] 14811#0: *48 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/css/trainee_default.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/css/trainee_default.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:32:27 [error] 14812#0: *68 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/css/tutor_default.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/css/tutor_default.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:32:27 [error] 14812#0: *79 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/django_summernote/django_summernote.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/django_summernote/django_summernote.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:32:27 [error] 14812#0: *82 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/django_summernote/summernote.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/django_summernote/summernote.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:32:27 [error] 14811#0: *38 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/js/trainee_app_browse_by_category.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/js/trainee_app_browse_by_category.js HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:32:27 [error] 14812#0: *78 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/js/trainee_app_accounts.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/js/trainee_app_accounts.js HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:34:35 [error] 14812#0: *83 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/css/master.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/css/master.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:34:35 [error] 14812#0: *85 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/css/normalize.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/css/normalize.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:34:35 [error] 14812#0: *86 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/css/tutor_default.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/css/tutor_default.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:34:35 [error] 14812#0: *87 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/css/trainee_default.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/css/trainee_default.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:34:35 [error] 14812#0: *88 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/django_summernote/django_summernote.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/django_summernote/django_summernote.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:34:35 [error] 14812#0: *89 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/django_summernote/summernote.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/django_summernote/summernote.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:34:35 [error] 14812#0: *83 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/js/trainee_app_browse_by_category.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/js/trainee_app_browse_by_category.js HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:34:35 [error] 14812#0: *85 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/js/trainee_app_accounts.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/js/trainee_app_accounts.js HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:34:40 [error] 14812#0: *90 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/css/master.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/css/master.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:34:41 [error] 14812#0: *92 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/css/trainee_default.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/css/trainee_default.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:34:41 [error] 14812#0: *91 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/css/normalize.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/css/normalize.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:34:41 [error] 14812#0: *93 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/django_summernote/django_summernote.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/django_summernote/django_summernote.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:34:41 [error] 14812#0: *94 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/css/tutor_default.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/css/tutor_default.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:34:41 [error] 14812#0: *95 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/django_summernote/summernote.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/django_summernote/summernote.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28", referrer: "http://128.199.240.28/"
2014/10/29 00:45:07 [error] 14941#0: *29 open() "/home/django/ssupchang/static/assets/css/master.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.205.81.48, server: _, request: "GET /static/assets/css/master.css HTTP/1.1", host: "128.199.240.28"
```

Comment: Which port are you trying to run on? Do you have permission to do so?

Comment: Conf file says am port 80 is being used. Here are the conf files https://gist.github.com/krishnateja/21b9507e510de8845e01

snapshot of browser http://bit.ly/1u430NJ
snapshot of settings.py http://bit.ly/1wb6aOr

Comment: I would recommend viewing the nginx error log first:

`tail --lines 30 /var/log/nginx/error.log`

The above will let you know exactly what is causing the 500 error without pulling your hair out. Once you have done that, you may have your answer since setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to `127.0.0.1` had no change in your outcome. Perhaps posting the last error will help us/you as well.

Comment: You're saying your JS/CSS files are not loading. Have you collected your static files and set a static root in django settings? I know for default stuff like admin, you need to collect static files. 

    python manage.py collectstatic --help

Comment: Weird thing is I restarted the server with service gunicorn restart and app is working fine with Debug=False Now struggling with loading the css files - here is the snapshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/yybkmuvwpz4git6/console.png?dl=0 I used this tail --lines 30 /var/log/nginx/error.log command and added the logs output above. All the errors say failed (2: No such file or directory)

Also please the admin panel - http://128.199.240.28/admin_panel/

Comment: fixed it, this is because of the conflict between **STATIC_ROOT = /static/ in settings.py** and configuration in **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django** file, remove this part and do not forget to restart the service with **service nginx restart**

`location /media  {
        alias /home/django/supchang/media;
    }`
    

    `location /static {
        alias /home/django/ssupchang/static; 
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `ALLOWEDHOSTS`, which is incorrect.

The proper name is `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, as seen in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts).

Comment: My bad formatting went wrong when I tried pasting it here - It is ALLOWED_HOSTS that I have used in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost'] or ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']

Answer (score 0):

Your allowed host should be your ip, or domain name something like this format

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS =['.domainname',]
```